# ROSSerializationException while publishing PointCloud2 Message

Tags: ros, python, sensor-msgs, rospy, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

when my node is publishing a PointCloud2 message I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rosuser/ros_workspace/src/udp_83b_adapter_eclipse_python/src/UDP83BAdapter.py", line 141, in <module>
    adapter.init()
  File "/home/rosuser/ros_workspace/src/udp_83b_adapter_eclipse_python/src/UDP83BAdapter.py", line 137, in init
    self.receive()
  File "/home/rosuser/ros_workspace/src/udp_83b_adapter_eclipse_python/src/UDP83BAdapter.py", line 43, in receive
    self.sonarToPointfield()
  File "/home/rosuser/ros_workspace/src/udp_83b_adapter_eclipse_python/src/UDP83BAdapter.py", line 128, in sonarToPointfield
    self.pub.publish(msg_pointcloud2)
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 801, in publish
    raise ROSSerializationException(str(e))
rospy.exceptions.ROSSerializationException: field fields[].offset must be unsigned integer type
```

The message is completely generated by my python script.
Here is the fields declaration and initialization:

```
    #  Create 4 PointFields as channel description
    msg_pf1 = smsgs.PointField()
    msg_pf1.name = np.str('x')
    msg_pf1.offset = np.uint32(0)
    msg_pf1.datatype = np.uint8(7)
    msg_pf1.count = np.uint32(1)
    
    msg_pf2 = smsgs.PointField()
    msg_pf2.name = np.str('y')
    msg_pf2.offset = np.uint32(4)
    msg_pf2.datatype = np.uint8(7)
    msg_pf2.count = np.uint32(1)
    
    msg_pf3 = smsgs.PointField()
    msg_pf3.name = np.str('z')
    msg_pf3.offset = np.uint32(8)
    msg_pf3.datatype = np.uint8(7)
    msg_pf3.count = np.uint32(1)
    
    msg_pf4 = smsgs.PointField()
    msg_pf4.name = np.str('intensity')
    msg_pf4.offset = np.uint32(12)
    msg_pf4.datatype = np.uint8(2)
    msg_pf4.count = np.uint32(1)
```

And somewhere later in the code:

```
    msg_pointcloud2.fields = [msg_pf1, msg_pf2, msg_pf3, msg_pf4]
```

I'm using python/rospy.
Another strange thing: I can run the script. As soon as I try to access the message (e.g. via rostopic echo) the error comes up.

Does anybody have a idea why this is happening? What can I try to debug?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61821/rosserializationexception-while-publishing-pointcloud2-message/) by [Josch](https://answers.ros.org/users/3932/josch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 230 on 2013-04-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably shouldn't use numpy types, but native data types. The `offsets` field is supposed to be a native python `long` instead of `numpy.uint32`. Instead of:

```
msg_pf1.offset = np.uint32(0)
```

just write:

```
msg_pf1.offset = 0
```

... and so on for all other fields.

Regarding your other comment:

> I'm using python/rospy. Another strange thing: I can run the script. As soon as I try to access the message (e.g. via rostopic echo) the error comes up.

This is probably because the serialization code isn't called until there is a subscriber to the topic.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Josch](https://answers.ros.org/users/3932/josch/) on 2013-04-30**:
This was too easy to come in my mind :-D. Thank you!

Another question: When python asks for a unsiged int list, what do I have to give it?
An easy list filled with integers is not correct, unfortunately.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-04-30**:
Are you sure that a simple list of integers (like `[1, 2, 3, 4]`) doesn't work? I'm 99% sure it works.

**Comment by [Josch](https://answers.ros.org/users/3932/josch/) on 2013-04-30**:
Good point. They were numpy datatypes. I changed them to usual types now (float, float, float, int).
Unfortunately python still says:
`field data[] must be unsigned integer type`
EDIT: Nevermind, another obvious mistake.